# iOS Application Rejected By Apple In-App purchase Subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, in-app

Hello Team I know lot of answer on the stack overflow but for me none of them work so please help me out I am facing this issue last 2 weeks I am done the all configuration on iTunes connect also.

**I got this message By APPLE**

We are unable to proceed with the review of your app until this issue has been addressed.

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business

We noticed that your app and its description did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b).

Your app's binary did not include:

- Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription
- Links to the privacy policy and terms of use

Your app's metadata did not include:

- Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription
- A link to the terms of use
- The length of the subscription
- A privacy policy in the Privacy Policy URL field of iTunes Connect

For your convenience, we've included Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) below.
You clearly and conspicuously disclose to users the following information regarding Your auto-renewing subscription:

- Title of publication or service
- Length of subscription (time period and/or content/services provided during each subscription period)
- Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate
- Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
- Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at
  least 24-hours before the end of the current period
- Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end
  of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
- Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be
  turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase
- Links to Your Privacy Policy and Terms of Use
- Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be
  forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication,
  where applicable

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app or its metadata to include the missing information. Adding the above information to the StoreKit modal alert is not sufficient;

the information must also be listed somewhere within the app itself, and it must be displayed clearly and conspicuously. 
If the above information is in your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide details on where to locate it.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: @MartinR I know lot of answer there but not working thats'y I asked this Question if you know answer then please give some input on that.

Comment: @Sanjeetverma  I am going to be be blunt here, I asked the similar question, but there are a lot of people on Stackoverflow who do not want you to ask the question like this, they want you to just go ahead and pay Apple for IAP, they say "their store their policies" but this is a very relevant question coz you must have spend your months of your time and its important for you to ask this question to the like minded individuals, I support this question.    What's the latest on this ?  Did you got it approved or still stuck ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to give privacy policy and payment details in description of App in iTunes.Because when user reading about app he can able to see terms and conditions for payments details.

And you need to mention in App-purchase details like it's monthly recurring or not **(Auto renewable)**, Price,Name and which feature he will get when he purchased.
Then apple will approve you app for payments.

For metadata missing you need to provide fully details in in-App purchase, Like screen shot of purchase screen.

Comment: Thanks for your Quickly response let me explain I did all configure on iTunes connect full-fill all information see my screen picture how I am doing for in-app purchase http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2438630/d69dd1d78a12bdbcdb8c7f4a17a6ea29

Comment: Now when use click first button Get stoked then one alter view appear who looks like this http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2438646/60e3dee3784a736648adc41432945d19 then click on Buy option it's proceed further can you pleases give more input on that I am facing this issue last 2 weeks

Comment: In this below get more stoked, You can give privacy policy URL, In that URL content you can mention Payment details with names.

Comment: Check these below points once


1)Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription **(Auto renewable or non auto renewable)**


 2) A link to the terms of use **(Terms and condition link in App as well in iTunes also)**


  3)The length of the subscription:(How many days, month or year)
  4)A privacy policy in the Privacy Policy URL field of iTunes Connect(Check in iTunes have you provided Privacy policy URL and its working or not, and also check contact us URL )

Comment: All mention above information where I have to put (iTunes connect or in our App?) if you have some reference or some sample app can you provide me. and second thing I am displaying the pop up for confirmation is it right or wrong I don't know I am doing right or wrong please guide me on this

Comment: @Sanjeetverma Hey I have same issue, How did you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: i have same issue

Comment: @Sanjeetverma I have the same issue, did u find any work around ?

Comment: @SivakrishnaPerla The issue was mine you have to fill out properly meta data in  in-app purchase section in Appstore, if meta data is not fill out properly then you will get above issue from apple side.